# What courses should be included as "Course Highlight" in Resume for Master's application?

Tags: masters, cv

I am writing my resume to apply for master's in computer science. My question is, what courses should I include as "Course Highlights" at the bottom of my bachelor's degree?

A) Are the courses which I got **great grades** the candidates? But I have a lot of them fortunately!

B) Or should I include **only** the courses which are **elective and important to my research interest**?

C) Should I include a course, which is mandatory for my bachelor's degree as I guess, that I had a great grade, and is **really important** for the field? I mean Algorithms Design if anyone is familiar with computer science.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but for 90% of computer scientists algorithm design courses are not remotely relevant to their life’s work, except for the purpose of passing poorly designed (but ubiquitous) interview exams.

Answer (score 2):

I am in physics, not computer science, and things may vary by field. But in my experience, it's very unusual to see "course[work] highlights" in an undergraduate resume, unless you have taken courses that are (a) relevant to your application, and (b) not the typical required courses that every applicant has taken. In particular, this section is not about grades. If your grades are excellent, you should list your GPA (or "GPA in major") in the same section where you list your school, degree type, etc.